# LINQ - узнать количество элементов после групирования по параметру из <Т>

Tags: c#, linq

Допустим есть некий список самолетов которые прилетают в аэропорты.

нужно через один линк-запрос получить результат вида

```
List<Аэропорт, количествоПрибывшихСамолетов>
```

Я додумался до

```
var rez = planes.GroupBy(i => new {i.Destination}).Where(g => g.Count() >= 1).ToList();
```

Что, конечно же, делает совсем не то, что мне нужно. Я не понимаю как вывести результат нужного мне вида

Я в SQL не силен, но запрос будет что-то вроде

```
SELECT Destination, Count(*)
FROM planes
GroupBy destination
Where Count(*) >= 1
```

А вот как в линк написать то же самое?

Comment: `planes.GroupBy(i => i.Destination).Select(g => new { Destination = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList()`

Comment: @ PetSerAl -- запости ответ как ответ и отмечу, идеально!

Comment: @PetSerAl, `Where` забыл

Comment: @Grundy При каком условии предикат `g => g.Count() >= 1` вернёт ложь?

Comment: @PetSerAl, когда count==0, но только сейчас подумал. что этого возможно не случится при таком запросе :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для построения Linq запросов проще использовать query-синтаксис

текущий запрос в этом синтаксисе будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var rez = (from plane in planes
           group plane by plane.Destination into grouppenPlanes
           where grouppenPlanes.Count()>1
           select grouppenPlanes)
          .ToList();
```

Все, что осталось сделать - просто указать в *select* что надо вернуть:

```
var rez = (from plane in planes
           group plane by plane.Destination into grouppenPlanes
           where grouppenPlanes.Count()>1
           select new {
               Destination = grouppenPlanes.Key,
               Counts = grouppenPlanes.Count()
           })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Grouppenwas, bitte? :)